# Web client for video streaming

Tags: video-streaming

I have a web cam that supports live video streaming. The problem is that the web interface it provides uses an activex control to display the video stream which only seems to work with internet explorer. I can watch the video stream using vlc, but i would like to set up a web page for less technical users who aren't using ie. Are there any clients/libraries in java/flash/whatever i could just plug the video stream in to?

Thanks

Comment: What video format does the camera use for streaming?

Comment: @second did you ever get a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **[Vlc Web plugin](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin/)**

For example

`<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" target="yourlinkhere"/>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  So that people later can understand this as a full answer, it would be great if you could provide details as to how this plugin helps to solve the issue of the questioner - link only answers are generally not well received by others here.  Thank you!